# How do I navigate to specific <tr> labels in HTML using R?

Tags: html, r

I want to extract the first `<tr>` label from each table using R. I've been trying to find the right selector using commands like firstchild, but I seem to be having trouble with the nested labels in the table. I'd greatly appreciate some help!

```
<center>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td bgcolor>...</td>
         <td bgcolor>...</td>
          </tr>
      <tr>
         <td bgcolor>...</td>
         <td bgcolor>...</td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</center>
<p></p>
<center>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td bgcolor>...</td>
         <td bgcolor>...</td>
          </tr>
      <tr>
         <td bgcolor>...</td>
         <td bgcolor>...</td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</center>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rvest`:

```
library(rvest)

html <- read_html(file)

trs <- html %>% html_nodes('table') %>% html_node('tr')
```

`trs` is a vector of `xml_nodeset`s which contains the `<tr>`s that you seek. You can print one like this:

```
toString(trs[1])

## "<tr>...</tr>\n"
```

Or you can extract the text within a `<tr>` like this:

```
trs[1] %>% html_text()

## "..."
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I think that there would still be a problem associated with finding the first <tr> label of each tree after all the <tr> labels have been extracted. If, for instance, there is a variable number of <tr> labels per table.

Comment: The code above gives you the first `<tr>` from each table *only*. Since there are two tables, the results in `trs` are two `<tr>`s, which are the first that you find in each table. Notice that the code gets all the tables, and then only one `<tr>`, which happens to be the first, from each table (that's why the code says `html_node('tr')`, singular, instead of getting all the `<tr>`s, which would have required `html_nodes('tr)`. Does this make sense? You can check this is how it works but putting some different text in each `<tr>` and see which ones get returned.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to use `td` in your rows.
Your code should be like this:

```
<center>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>...</td></tr>
      <tr><td>...</td></tr>
      <tr><td>...</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</center>
<p></p>
<center>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>...</td></tr>
      <tr><td>...</td></tr>
      <tr><td>...</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</center>
<p></p>
```

Now you can apply CSS rules to them like this:

```
table tbody tr:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```